# Up to date LXC template for Ubuntu

Tags: lxc

Currently we are using LXC to deploy a web application, each time we deploy a new and separate container is freshly built. The container is based on Ubuntu 14.04, but the problem is that the template seems to be based on the 14.04 release version, it is not up to date. Each deployment is taking longer and longer as apt-get update/upgrade need to process more packages.

LXC comes with a different template: 'download', which basically downloads an up to dat eversion of the requested release. Deploying this template is significantly faster as it has to upgrade (almost) no packages. However, the download template does not support the --bind-home option that we require.

Is there a way to get the ubuntu template to use a more up to date base container, or alternatively a way to have the download template with --bind-home?